# Solr start example: Connection refused error

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm following the quickstart example from [this page](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html#admin-collection), using a Mac with Yosemite and an up-to-date version of Java 7.

When I try launching Solr with "bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt" I get the following error:

```
Welcome to the SolrCloud example!


Starting up 2 Solr nodes for your example SolrCloud cluster.
Creating Solr home directory /Users/jg/Downloads/solr-5.0.0/example/cloud/node1/solr
Cloning Solr home directory /Users/jg/Downloads/solr-5.0.0/example/cloud/node1 into /Users/jg/Downloads/solr-5.0.0/example/cloud/node2

Starting up SolrCloud node1 on port 8983 using command:

solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node1/solr -p 8983   


Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8983 [/]  
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=7672). Happy searching!



Starting node2 on port 7574 using command:

solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node2/solr -p 7574 -z localhost:9983   


Waiting to see Solr listening on port 7574 [/]  
Started Solr server on port 7574 (pid=7763). Happy searching!

Connecting to ZooKeeper at localhost:9983
Uploading /Users/jg/Downloads/solr-5.0.0/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf for config gettingstarted to ZooKeeper at localhost:9983
WARN  - 2015-04-05 01:13:01.940; org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI; Request to http://192.168.1.217:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=list failed due to: Connection refused, sleeping for 5 seconds before re-trying the request ...

Creating new collection 'gettingstarted' using command:
http://192.168.1.217:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=gettingstarted&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&collection.configName=gettingstarted

WARN  - 2015-04-05 01:13:06.973; org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI; Request to http://192.168.1.217:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=gettingstarted&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&collection.configName=gettingstarted failed due to: Connection refused, sleeping for 5 seconds before re-trying the request ...

ERROR: Connection refused
```

And it appears that the "gettingstarted" collection is never actually created, as my "cloud" screen is blank.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you open http://192.168.1.217:8983/solr? Imo this should be localhost and not some random (?) ip.

Answer (score 0):

On your mac, check the hosts file and make sure the file has these lines

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```